# vimscript to skip a block of text with lines containing similar words

Tags: vimscript, cursor-movement, functions

I need a little help with some vimscript-ing.

I have a huge log file with multiple blocks of text resembling the following:

```
[log file start]
...
...
Information: Setting NDR rule shield_rule on net a
Information: Setting NDR rule shield_rule on net b
Information: Setting NDR rule shield_rule on net c
Information: Setting NDR rule shield_rule on net d
Information: Setting NDR rule shield_rule on net e
Information: Setting NDR rule shield_rule on net f
Information: Setting NDR rule shield_rule on net g
Information: Setting NDR rule shield_rule on net h
Information: Setting NDR rule shield_rule on net i
Information: Setting NDR rule shield_rule on net j
Information: Setting NDR rule shield_rule on net k
Information: Setting NDR rule shield_rule on net l
Information: Setting NDR rule shield_rule on net m
Information: Setting NDR rule shield_rule on net n
Information: Setting NDR rule shield_rule on net o
Information: Setting NDR rule shield_rule on net p
Information: Setting NDR rule shield_rule on net q
Information: Setting NDR rule shield_rule on net r
...
...
….  <10,000 more lines like above>
….
Information: Updating global clock route.
[log file end]
```

I would like to write a function bound to `;b` that allows me to skip the entire
block of similar text. For example, place the cursor at the 1st line of text,
hit `;b` and have the cursor move to the 1st line immediately after the block of
similar text.

I realize I can navigate to the end of the file and search backwards for
`Information: Setting NDR rule` but there may be multiple block occurrences of
the text and a backwards search would bring me to the end of the last block.

This is what I have so far:

```
function! SkipBlockDn()
  let ref = getline(v:lnum)
  execute "normal! j"
  let line = getline(v:lnum)
  "
  "Help needed here to split up the line into words
  "Do a word by word comparison between ref and line
  "If current line and ref match like 80% or so, consider the match close enough and move to next line
  "
  while (line ==# ref)
    execute "normal! j"
    let line = getline(v:lnum)
  endwhile

endfunction
nmap <silent>  ;b  :call SkipBlockDn()<CR>
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I've made a few [edit]s to your post. (PS you can write `normal! j` without `execute`. You can also use `getline('.')`. Then there is `:help split()` or `:help =~#`.)

Answer (score 1):

Let me start by offering a solution that you can implement in an ad-hoc fashion, without the need to write Vimscript or pre-define any mappings.

You can use the [`\@!`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%40%21) zero-width negative look-ahead item as part of a pattern to only match lines that do *not* start with a specific sequence of characters.

In your case, you could use a simple search such as the one below:

```
/^\(Information: Setting NDR rule shield_rule\)\@!
```

You can also use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> command from the search input to help you enter the first few words of the current line. (See [`:help c_CTRL-R`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-R).)

For example, you can yank the 6 first words (separated by whitespace) of the current line with `0y6W` and then use `/^\(` followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>"</kbd> to read from the unnamed register, then `\)\@!` to finish entering the search pattern.

Alternatively, after entering the preamble of `/^\(`, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to insert the line under the cursor, then use <kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to trim the last part of the line you don't want in the match, and finally close the pattern with `\)\@!` and execute the search.

Of course, you can automate that into a Vimscript function and add a mapping for it. If I were to do so, I'd build a pattern such as the one I described, then use `call search()` to execute the search with this pattern. The tricky part in writing a function and creating a mapping is probably covering the corner cases (empty lines, lines that are too short, search metacharacters, customize percentage of the line to use, etc.) When using an ad-hoc procedure, it's usually easy to spot those issues and adapt the search to cope with them.